# Spring-boot: Join table with @OneToMany annotation return empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I recently started learning Spring Boot and I have a problem. I have two tables (Categories, subcategories) with a one to many relationship. I am having trouble creating this relationship. When requesting the output of all categories, the list of subcategories is empty, but in the database tables are created correctly.

Please tell me what can be wrong.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name ="subcategory")
@Data
public class SubCategoryEntity  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne( targetEntity = CategoryEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private CategoryEntity category;

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@Data
public class CategoryEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String img;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = SubCategoryEntity.class)
    private Set<SubCategoryEntity> subcategories;

}
```

```java
@GetMapping("/categories")
public List<CategoryEntity> getCategories() {
    return categoryRepository.findAll();
}
```

Attempt to get data:
[image: attempt to get data]

Here I tried to get a list of categories and subcategories, but the list of subcategories is empty, although it is not.

Comment: Can you verify that the data in the tables is correct? I.e. that in `SubCategoryEntity` the link to `CategoryEntity` is correctly set. The hibernate mapping itself seems correct. Since you want to eagerly load the subcategories, you can try to also add `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the database. The tables are linked
I just tried to query a list of subcategories, and this is something like the truth
I need something similar only with a list of categories
This is getting a list of subcategories
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "kkkk",
        "category": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Техника для дома",
            "img": "фыва",
            "subcategories": []
        }
    }
]